# The efficient approach to generate a string of prime numbers with length 10005

Tags: string, primes

I need to generate a string consists of prime numbers. The string will be like "235711..." and the length of the string needs to be 10005.

My thought on implementing this:

1. Generate the prime number 1 by 1
2. Concatenate each prime
3. Check the length of the string, if it is less than 10005, then continue the process

May I ask what would be your comment on this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What comments are you looking for? Are you having a problem with your algorithm?

Comment: You would do better to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which is more efficient than testing numbers one by one.  The sieve is far quicker for finding primes in bulk.  You will need an over-estimate of how far you need to look to get enough primes to set the initial range for the sieve.